# several questions about this sml recursion function

Tags: recursion, dynamic-memory-allocation, sml, tail-recursion, static-allocation

1. When `f(x-1)` is called, is it calling `f(x) = x+10` or `f(x) = if ...`
2. Is this a tail recursion?
3. How should I rewrite it using static / dynamic allocation?

   ```
   let fun f(x) = x + 10
   in
       let fun f(x) = if x < 1 then 0 else f(x-1)
       in f(3)
       end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Before addressing your questions, here are some observations about your code:

- There are two functions `f`, one inside the other. They're different from one another.
- To lessen this confusion you can rename the inner function to `g`:

  ```
  let fun f(x) = x + 10
  in
      let fun g(x) = if x < 1 then 0 else g(x-1)
      in g(3)
      end
  end
  ```
- This clears up which function calls which by the following rules: The outer `f` is defined inside the outer `in`-`end`, but is immediately *shadowed* by the inner `f`. So any reference to `f` on the right-hand side of the inner `fun f(x) = if ...` is shadowed because `fun` enables self-recursion. And any reference to `f` within the inner `in`-`end` is shadowed

---

- In the following tangential example the right-hand side of an inner declaration `f` does *not* shadow the outer `f` if we were using `val` rather than `fun`:

  ```
  let fun f(x) = if (x mod 2 = 0) then x - 10 else x + 10
  in
      let val f = fn x => f(x + 2) * 2
      in f(3)
      end
  end
  ```

  If the inner `f` is renamed to `g` in this second piece of code, it'd look like:

  ```
  let fun f(x) = if (x mod 2 = 0) then x - 10 else x + 10
  in
      let val g = fn x => f(x + 2) * 2
      in g(3)
      end
  end
  ```

  The important bit is that the `f(x + 2)` part was not rewritten into `g(x + 2)` because `val` means that references to `f` are outer `f`s, not the `f` being defined, because a `val` is not a self-recursive definition. So any reference to an `f` within that definition would have to depend on it being available in the outer scope.

  But the `g(3)` bit *is* rewritten because between `in`-`end`, the inner `f` (now `g`) *is* shadowing. So whether it's a `fun` or a `val` does not matter with respect to the shadowing of `let`-`in`-`end`.
- *(There are some more details wrt. `val rec` and the exact scope of a `let val f = ...` that I haven't elaborated on.)*

---

As for your questions,

1. You should be able to answer this now. A nice way to provide the answer is 1) rename the inner function for clarity, 2) evaluate the code by hand using substitution (one rewrite per line, `~>` denoting a rewrite, so I don't mean an SML operator here).

   Here's an example of how it'd look with my *second* example (not your code):

   ```
      g(3)
   ~> (fn x => f(x + 2) * 2)(3)
   ~> f(3 + 2) * 2
   ~> f(5) * 2
   ~> (if (5 mod 2 = 0) then 5 - 10 else 5 + 10) * 2
   ~> (if (1 = 0) then 5 - 10 else 5 + 10) * 2
   ~> (5 + 10) * 2
   ~> 15 * 2
   ~> 30
   ```

   Your evaluation by hand would look different and possibly conclude differently.
2. What is tail recursion? Provide a definition and ask if your code satisfies that definition.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by rewriting it using static / dynamic allocation. You'll have to elaborate.